# How to enable screen sharing when using networkd in netplan in Ubuntu 18.04.3?

Tags: vnc, netplan, gnome-control-center, vino, systemd-networkd

I have configured a bond and 2 other network ports in my *netplan* configuration file, which works fine.  The problem I face now is that I can not find a way to enable screen sharing since no networks are shown is settings, so it is not possible to set in the *Gnome Control Center*.  I have tried manually making setting changes with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino network-interface 'bond0'
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
```

But neither fixed the problem. I have a similar post here: [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1500498/1110788).
Is it possible to enable screen sharing without using *NetworkManager* as the renderer in *netplan*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was not able to figure out how to get screen sharing to work with *networkd* as the renderer, but I did figure how to get it working with *NetworkManager*.  I was able to get the bond configured using *nmtui*.  I followed the instructions [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configure_bonding_using_the_text_user_interface_nmtui).  But even with a properly configured bond, it would only work if the original 1GbE port was not active. Otherwise, Gnome settings would not let me choose the new bond for sharing.  To overcome this, I used a method described [here](https://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2019/02/set-the-default-route-via-nmcli.html):

```
nmcli c mod eno1 ipv4.never-default true
nmcli c mod eno1 ipv6.never-default true
nmcli c down eno1; nmcli c up eno1
```

I have verified with a couple of reboots.