# Make a permanent route change to a specific IP through a specific interface

Tags: networking, server, routing

I have a setup where I use a 10G bond to work with a remote system, but it intermittently gets disconnected, as traffic will occasionally be routed over another interface.  I think I have the problem solved with the following routing for 192.168.0.31:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 nm-bond
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    90000  0        0 eno2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno2
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 nm-bond
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     90000  0        0 eno2
192.168.0.31    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 nm-bond
```

Seems to work so far.  Is there a better approach?  How do I make this permanent?

I have tried many variations of this netplan file: 01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
            nm-bond:
                addresses:
                    - 192.168.0.1/23
                routes:
                    - to: 192.168.0.31
                      via: 0.0.0.0
                      metric: 0
```

Probably the basic principal of converting the `route -n` table item to a netplan entry is where my problem is.  Still learning...

Actually, my end goal is to have all traffic to/from the internet to use eno2 and intranet to use nm-bond.  I have port forwarding on my router to forward https to the IP address assigned to eno3.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **persistent static routes** with netplan.
See some examples: 
https://netplan.io/examples#using-multiple-addresses-with-multiple-gateways
Also see : https://askubuntu.com/a/992641/77093

For your use case this should look like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno2:
     addresses:
       - 192.168.1.x/24
     [ ... ]

    nm-bond:
     addresses:
       -  192.168.0.x/24
     [ ... ]
     routes:
       - to: 192.168.0.31/32
         via: 0.0.0.0
     [ ... ]
```

Comment: When I used `sudo ip route add 192.168.0.31 dev nm-bond`, the routing table is updated as expected.  But when I add this to the netplan: `network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
            nm-bond:
                addresses:
                    - 192.168.0.x/24
                routes:
                    - to: 192.168.0.31/32
                      via: 0.0.0.0
                      metric: 0` and restart networking, I don't see the change with `route -n`

Comment: @Rick : plz edit your question and paste your original netplan config file, i will be able to help more precisely

Comment: I just tried `netplan try` and got this error message `Cannot determine operstate of nm-bond: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/net/nm-bond/operstate'`

Comment: After some searching, I am concerned that using NetworkManager as renderer is why I can get this working.  networkd makes sense, but I could not get screen sharing to work as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1187637/1014175)